# How to store data each time a user presses a button in Firebase (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am an experienced MySQL user but I am a newbie to json and firebase. I am trying to make an activity where a user is able to enter data and I save it to my db in firebase. I achieved my goal but here is the problem. When I save it(I think) I need to specify a child element with a string. Since this child element is static,every time a user enters a question it overwrites the existing one in my database. How can I fix this and how can I get the data back? Here is that part of my code.

```
 private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;


firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()==null){
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class));
        }
        FirebaseUser user=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


Info info=new Info(question,answer,a,b,c,d);
                databaseReference.child("secondQuestion").setValue(info);
//info is a new object which takes 6 string as an input. 
  // As you can see, I declare a string inside .child and it overwrites the data stored in it
```

Comment: You may want to store your questions in a list-like structure: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data. Using `push` will generate a unique ID for your question, which you may need to save somewhere to retrieve later on.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew commented, it is indeed normal to add items to a (semi-chronological) list using `push`.

They're logically similar to a auto-increment field in MySQL, but have a (very) different format. See [this post about why Firebase doesn't use the +1 style increments](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) and [this post on the push IDs](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html).

If your questions already have a property that uniquely identifies them, you should probably use that as the key. So say that you're storing a list of Firebase Authentication users, you'd store each user under their `uid`. Or if the question text must be unique, you should probably store each question under (a hashed derivative of) their text.

Comment: I see. So can I do something like the following?  Whenever a user tries to enter a new question, I want to check each key in my db to see if it is a duplicate of a previous question. Because if I do not and I try to add the question to db I think that it will overwrite the previous question, instead of rejecting the addition of the new question

Comment: Keys are automatically unique.Values on the other hand are not. You can easily prevent overwriting data in security rules: `".write": "!data.exists()"`